# what's the MonadReader's Instance defined mean?

Tags: haskell

The `MonadReader`'s Instance `MonadReader r (ReaderT rm)` was defined as following :

```
instance Monad m => MonadReader r (ReaderT r m) where
    ask = ReaderT.ask
    local = ReaderT.local
    reader = ReaderT.reader
```

in `ask = ReaderT.ask`, the second ask is what MonadReader Instance ?

Thank you very much:)

Comment: `ReaderT.ask` is the `ask` from the qualified import of `ReaderT`. The `ask` being referred to is [this one](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html#v:ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second `ask` isn't from any instance at all. It's a normal function defined in [`Control.Monad.Trans.Reader`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html#v:ask) (and its type is `Monad m => ReaderT r m r`).

It's like doing the following:

```
data Color = Red | Green | Blue

myShow :: Color -> String
myShow c = case c of
    Red   -> "(red)"
    Green -> "(green)"
    Blue  -> "(blue)"

instance Show Color where
    show = myShow
```

Here `myShow` plays the role of `ReaderT.ask` as a separate function.